# Maven: how to find the plugin prefix for github-release-plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, prefix

I want to use this maven plugin: https://github.com/jutzig/github-release-plugin

Here is the POM configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>de.jutzig</groupId>
    <artifactId>github-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>github-upload</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>release</goal>
            </goals>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <releaseName>${project.version}</releaseName>
                <tag>Initial Release</tag>
                <artifact>${project.build.directory}/${assemblyName}.zip</artifact>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The question is how to call the release goal from the command line?

I tried: `mvn github-release-plugin:release`

This fails with:  `No plugin found for prefix 'github-release-plugin' in the current project and in the plugin groups`

I'm fairly new to maven and wonder how to find out the correct prefix needed for this plugin.

Comment: Try `mvn de.jutzig:github-release-plugin:1.1.0:release`? Checkout the `Executing Your First Mojo` section [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html). It also mentions a few tips on reducing the verboseness of the command.

Comment: On the other hand, you've attached the `release` goal to the `deploy` phase of the `default` maven lifecycle, so running `mvn deploy` should run your `release` goal too really. Read about maven [lifecycles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`mvn de.jutzig:github-release-plugin:1.1.0:release`

Checkout the **Executing Your First Mojo** section [here‌​](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html). It also mentions a few tips on reducing the verboseness of the command, one of which is **'Attaching the Mojo to the Build Lifecycle'**, which you've done anyway - you just gotta take advantage of it by running:

`mvn deploy`

Read about the maven lifecycles to understand the various `phase`s and how you can bind `goal`s to a specific `phase` in a `lifecycle` [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).